# Not Getting output of Expect Script in Crontab

Tags: cron, solaris, expect

I've created an Expect Script (.exp) to get the raw file in other server. Then, I also have .sh file to call my .exp. It's working well when I tried to run it in a usual way (./call_expect.sh). But when I scheduled it in CRONTAB, no raw data fetch and expect script didn't response. I am confused right now, I don't know if there's a problem in my header as they will conflict or if there's a problem in crontab.

SAMPLE EXPECT (directory.exp)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

package require Expect
# set Variables
set USER {USER1234}
set PASSWORD {PASSWORD12345}
set NODE {test_server}
set DIR {/Daily/TESTING}
set PROMPT {$}
set COMMAND0 {ls -lrt Daily/TESTING | grep dr | grep -v tar | awk {'print $9'} | sort | grep ^2}
set quit_COMMAND {exit}


spawn ssh $USER@$NODE
expect {
  "assword:"
}
send "$PASSWORD\r"

expect {
  "$PROMPT "
}
send "$COMMAND0\r"

expect {
  "$PROMPT "
}
send "exit\r"
```

SAMPLE .SH (call_expect.sh)

```
#!/bin/ksh

{locations . . . }

${BIN}/directory.exp | dos2unix | grep ^2 > ${CONFIG}/.list_dir.tmp

previous_directory=`cat ${CONFIG}/.list_dir.tmp | tail -2 | head -1`
latest_directory=`cat ${CONFIG}/.list_dir.tmp | tail -1  | head -1`

echo "`date` Previous Dir: ${previous_directory}   Latest Dir: ${latest_directory}"
```

I'm using Solaris 5.10.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're getting errors from the awk command: single quotes appear to confuse awk (I'm testing this on a Mac, so your awk may behave differently)

```bsh
$ seq 10 | awk "'print \$9'"
awk: cmd. line:1: 'print $9'
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

awk demands braces for the action body.

Try this:

```
set COMMAND0 {ls ... | awk {{print $9}} | ...}
```

The outer braces are Tcl (and expect) quoting, the inner braces are for awk.